# Is it possible to color vim vertical indentation lines depending on the indentation level?

Tags: indentation

I'm using vim 8.

In the attached picture you see yellow vertical lines that indicate the indentations of a code.

[image]

Is it possible to color depending on their indentation level? E.g.

all vertical indentation lines on indentation level 1 should be red

all vertical indentation lines on indentation level 2 should be yellow

all vertical indentation lines on indentation level 3 should be green

etc.

PS: If it is of any relevance: I'm using https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine
That plugin doesn't have an option to color the vertical indentation lines  dependent on the indentation level

Comment: no it is not possible.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Why not?

Comment: Because it is not possible?

Comment: but you could use different line styles for different levels with `let g:indentLine_char_list = ['|', '¦', '┆', '┊']` if this helps.

Comment: You may also like the [vim-indent-guides plugin](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides). It does not color the lines, but visualizes indentation levels based on alternating colors of white spaces.

Comment: @Wolfson Unicode has [circled numbers](https://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2460.html) that might be useful in this context.

Answer (score 0):

here is how

use this plugin and follow the instructions in the README.md

https://github.com/lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim

Comment: Hi @Kalindu, it would be more helpful if you provide the answer or specific context your answer. Often times, README files can be detailed and cover many topics.

Comment: This only works for Neovim, not Vim.